# SmartGit 18.2 preview 8 #13132 compatibility with Mac OSX Mojave 10.14

Tags: smartgit

I have upgraded my MacBook Pro to the stable Mojave 10.14 version.

I noticed that the latest version of smartgit has issues displaying lists.

For example in the last of modified files, only the first 4 files are shown and the rest are not...as if the total number of modified files is 4 even though there are more files modified. Please take into consideration that 4 is a random number.

One other thing I noticed that when a row in a list is selected then the content of the row disappears.

Anyone else facing the same issue?

[image: There are 6 modified files but only 4 are showing]

[image: Notice that when the second row is selected the text disappears]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the *current* compatibility between a Software tool and an operating system won't help future readers. Instead, the vendor of the Software tool should be contacted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a bug report.